# How do I get the current time in a different TimeZone in Delphi?

Tags: delphi

How do i get current time from different time zones in Delphi.
If i use TidSNTP it will only give me the time zone in my locale.

Answer (score 17):

You can easily convert local time to different time zone with [delphi-tzdb (Time Zone Database for Delphi)](https://github.com/pavkam/tzdb).

Following is example from its [documentation](https://github.com/pavkam/tzdb/wiki/Code-Examples).

```
var
  LSydney: TTimeZone;
  LMadeUpLocalTime, LUniversalTime,
    LSydneyTime: TDateTime;
begin
  // Get the Sydney time zone 
  LSydney := TBundledTimeZone.GetTimeZone('Australia/Sydney');

  // Encode a local date/time value -- 14th March 2009 at 12:45:00 PM 
  LMadeUpLocalTime := EncodeDateTime(2009, 03, 14, 12, 45, 00, 00);

  // Find out what was the time in Sydney at that moment 
  LUniversalTime := TTimeZone.Local.ToUniversalTime(LMadeUpLocalTime);
  LSydneyTime := LSydney.ToLocalTime(LUniversalTime);

  WriteLn(Format('When in my time zone the time was %s, in Sydney it was %s.',
   [DateTimeToStr(LMadeUpLocalTime), DateTimeToStr(LSydneyTime)]));
end;
```

Comment: This is an excellent Delphi resource.  And since it is based on the IANA timezone database, it can easily be updated with the latest data, for example when a Pacific country moves across the dateline or Argentina changes its daylight saving dates and rules again.