# How to convert an UTC datetime to a specified Time zone?

Tags: windows, datetime, delphi, winapi, timezone

Seems easy but I didn't find a way to convert an UTC datetime to a specified timezone. I found how to convert an UTC date time to local date-time, but now I want to convert to a specific timezone (i.e. for example Moscow time)

For example in c# we can do:

```
// user-specified time zone
TimeZoneInfo southPole =
    TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Antarctica/South Pole Standard Time");

// an UTC DateTime
DateTime utcTime = new DateTime(2007, 07, 12, 06, 32, 00, DateTimeKind.Utc);

// DateTime with offset
DateTimeOffset dateAndOffset =
    new DateTimeOffset(utcTime, southPole.GetUtcOffset(utcTime));

Console.WriteLine(dateAndOffset);
```

But how to do in Delphi ?

Comment: [`SystemTimeToTzSpecificLocalTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/timezoneapi/nf-timezoneapi-systemtimetotzspecificlocaltime)

Comment: Despite the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/minwinbase/ns-minwinbase-systemtime) claiming, that this structure were to represent time in UTC, it doesn't appear to be capable of that. The valid range of seconds is *"0 through 59"*. To represent UTC, this value would need to have a range of 0 through 60.

Comment: @RbMm - Actually, one should use `SystemTimeToTzSpecificLocalTimeEx` instead.  See the reasoning in my answer below.

Comment: @IInspectable - While UTC carries a leap second in its formal specification, the vast majority of date/time APIs (in any language/platform) do not represent it.  That doesn't mean they don't use UTC.  Either way, it's not relevant to the question asked here.

Comment: @mat: It *is* relevant to the question asked. There's a difference between GMT and UTC (namely leap seconds). And I'm not sure what definition you subscribe to *"vast majority"*. C++ has acknowledged the need for different clocks (including UTC), that do carry the formal specification into the [implementation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/utc_clock).

Comment: The question is about converting from a datetime in UTC to a local time zone.  That implies an existing `TDateTime` or similar object already constructed, with UTC as its reference point.  Nowhere in the question does it say that they are having trouble creating a UTC datetime with the leap second in it.  Nowhere in the question are leap seconds mentioned at all.  As for majority, .NET, Java, Python, Go, JavaScript, and AFIK: *Delphi* which is relevant here.  (And presumably more.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A few things:

- `"Antarctica/South Pole Standard Time"` isn't a real time zone identifier.  I assume you gave that in jest, but it makes it unclear as to whether you want to use Windows time zone identifiers (like `"Eastern Standard Time"`), or IANA time zone identifiers (like `"America/New_York"`).
- Assuming you want to use Windows identifiers, you can indeed use the functions in the Win32 API.  The comment in the question suggested the wrong API however.  You should instead use [`SystemTimeToTzSpecificLocalTimeEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/timezoneapi/nf-timezoneapi-systemtimetotzspecificlocaltimeex).

  - It uses the [`DYNAMIC_TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/timezoneapi/ns-timezoneapi-dynamic_time_zone_information) structure, which have been available since Windows Vista.  To get one of those from a named Windows time zone identifier, use the [`EnumDynamicTimeZoneInformation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/timezoneapi/nf-timezoneapi-enumdynamictimezoneinformation) function to loop through the system time zones until you find the one matching on the `TimeZoneKeyName` field.
  - The "dynamic" structures are important to use, and should always be preferred over their older counterparts.  They allow access to changes in time zones and daylight saving time rules that are stored in the Windows registry.  Without them, you only get access to the *current* rule, which might not be the correct rule for the date you are converting.
- If you instead wanted to use IANA time zone identifiers, use the [Delphi tzdb library](https://github.com/pavkam/tzdb), as shown [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11280980/634824).

  - If you are uncertain of which to use, I highly recommend this approach.  IANA identifiers are inter-operable with other operating systems, programming languages, frameworks, and libraries.  (Windows identifiers, less so.)